# Check linearity in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

In order to check linearity in logistic regression ->

Is `independent1` and `independent2`variable linear related to the log-odds of `depdendent`?

I would like optimize this (working) calculations:

This is the code:

```
# Check Linearity  ---------------------------------------------------------

# quartiles of independent1
quantile(df$independent1, probs=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))


table(df$dependent[df$independent1<52])
table(df$dependent[df$independent1>=52 & df$independent1 < 60])
table(df$dependent[df$independent1>=60 & df$independent1 < 73])
table(df$dependent[df$independent1>=73 & df$independent1 < 91])

p1 <- mean(df$dependent[df$independent1<52])
p2 <- mean(df$dependent[df$independent1>=52 & df$independent1 < 60])
p3 <- mean(df$dependent[df$independent1>=60 & df$independent1 < 73])
p4 <- mean(df$dependent[df$independent1>=73 & df$independent1 < 91])
probs <- c(p1, p2, p3, p4)

# calculate the log-odds
logits <- log(probs/(1-probs))

# quartiles of independent1
q <- quantile(df$independent1, probs=seq(0,1,0.25))

# calculate median independent1 for each of the 4 groups
meds <- c( median(df$independent1[ df$independent1<q[2]]),
           median(df$independent1[ df$independent1>=q[2] & df$independent1<q[3]]),
           median(df$independent1[ df$independent1>=q[3] & df$independent1<q[4]]),
           median(df$independent1[ df$independent1>=q[4]])
)

plot(meds, logits, main="xxx",
     xlab = "independent1",
     ylab = "log-odds(dependent|independent1)", las=1)
```

For one variable this might be ok. But I have more independent variables. So how could I optimize this code (checking and plotting) for each independent variable (in this example `independent1` and `independent2`)

My dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(dependent = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), independent1 = c(84, 
49, 54, 75, 49, 70, 75, 42, 60, 72, 80, 73, 51, 61, 59, 78, 45, 
38, 78, 65, 91, 60, 39, 31, 42, 72, 41, 77, 73, 74, 39, 86, 71, 
55, 43, 75, 80, 75, 67, 74, 46, 70, 57, 66, 57, 72, 46, 52, 53, 
76, 57, 86, 67, 71, 57, 50, 76, 61, 41, 57, 62, 41, 64, 82, 53, 
75, 59, 38, 54, 56, 68, 63, 73, 26, 75, 76, 81, 46, 77, 53, 59, 
66, 51, 72, 80, 70, 39, 57, 62, 85, 84, 57, 73, 55, 70, 78, 66, 
69, 60, 51, 72, 68, 60, 62, 64, 44, 50, 59, 45, 81, 54, 68, 75, 
66, 54, 45, 52, 87, 44, 77, 49, 84, 68, 76, 82, 44, 58, 55, 69, 
33, 48, 62, 60, 76, 56, 73, 55, 58, 53, 53, 60, 52, 60, 41, 39, 
36, 38, 59, 54, 64), independent2 = c(23, 25, 34, 25, 31, 25, 
32, 19, 25, 28, 22, 18, 30, 26, 25, 25, 25, 19, 24, 27, 23, 28, 
39, 27, 30, 28, 22, 28, 25, 23, 18, 27, 27, 19, 25, 27, 26, 26, 
21, 26, 23, 28, 37, 32, 24, 32, 26, 23, 24, 27, 28, 25, 24, 22, 
34, 23, 35, 20, 29, 29, 21, 29, 25, 26, 23, 33, 25, 26, 29, 27, 
26, 28, 19, 22, 29, 22, 26, 35, 32, 29, 26, 23, 31, 30, 27, 28, 
23, 27, 34, 22, 24, 28, 21, 25, 18, 32, 21, 24, 31, 31, 24, 30, 
27, 23, 16, 26, 26, 19, 38, 21, 32, 34, 28, 19, 30, 24, 26, 24, 
40, 26, 15, 26, 28, 22, 25, 26, 31, 24, 26, 42, 26, 30, 28, 21, 
21, 19, 22, 20, 26, 31, 22, 25, 21, 20, 27, 27, 26, 29, 22, 24
)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: That procedure is not going to have much statistical power. You might instead want to put in a second-degree polynomial term.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for your quick reply. My aim is to check all assumptions of a logistic regression variable by variable. In case of continuous variables I then will dichotomize  the variable if the assumption is not fulfilled.

Comment: Yikes. The threat to statistical validity is getting even worse. Dichotomizing variables that have evidence of non-linear associations with logistic outcomes will be hiding (rather than investigating) potentially useful information. If you had applied my suggestion you could leave in the second-degree terms that satisfied whatever rule you chose for being "non-linear".

Comment: @IRTFM Could you please show me with an answer. I would be very grateful?

Comment: Independent of statistical power that might be as IRTFM states. But I am looking for a coding solution (more direct way) to check linearity in logistic regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate a somewhat different and decidedly more efficient method of splitting a variable that is to be used in a logistic regression model:

```
df$q41 <- with(df, cut(independent1, quantile(independent1), include = TRUE))
 # creates 4 level factor into roughly equally sized groups
 table(df$q41)
#--------------------
#[26,52] (52,60] (60,73] (73,91] 
#     39      37      39      35 

#Examine for "eyeball" trends in the log-odds of dependent 
fit1.q41 <- glm(dependent~q41+0, data=df, fam="binomial")
fit1.q41
#---------------------------
Call:  glm(formula = dependent ~ q41 + 0, family = "binomial", data = df)

Coefficients:
q41[26,52]  q41(52,60]  q41(60,73]  q41(73,91]  
    -3.638      -2.862      -2.918      -2.048  

Degrees of Freedom: 150 Total (i.e. Null);  146 Residual
Null Deviance:      207.9 
Residual Deviance: 65.52    AIC: 73.52
```

I chose to remove the intercept term because its presence prevented viewing the coefficient of the lowest group on the same scale as the upper 3. The coefficients are just the logits for the grouping I created. Compare:

```
> logits
[1] -3.555348 -2.740840 -2.970414 -2.169054
> coef(fit1.q41)
q41[26,52] q41(52,60] q41(60,73] q41(73,91] 
 -3.637586  -2.862201  -2.917771  -2.047693
```

I then tried to automate the process but ran into a bit of a problem because of the small numbers of events in one of the quartile groups, The ridiculously low coefficient for the lowest quartile in independent2 is from that lack of any events or "1"'s in that catergory. (An estimate log-odds of -19.566069 does rather point to a proportion of 0.)

```
 lapply( df[-1], function(x){cat(str(x)); IVq <- cut(x, quantile(x), include = TRUE); logits<-coef( summary(glm(df$dependent~IVq+0, fam="binomial"))); logits})
 num [1:150] 84 49 54 75 49 70 75 42 60 72 ...
 num [1:150] 23 25 34 25 31 25 32 19 25 28 ...
$independent1
            Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
IVq[26,52] -3.637586  1.0130639 -3.590678 3.298191e-04
IVq(52,60] -2.862201  0.7270292 -3.936845 8.256004e-05
IVq(60,73] -2.917771  0.7259663 -4.019155 5.840732e-05
IVq(73,91] -2.047693  0.5312796 -3.854266 1.160776e-04

$independent2
             Estimate   Std. Error     z value     Pr(>|z|)
IVq[15,23] -19.566069 1639.9716035 -0.01193074 9.904809e-01
IVq(23,26]  -3.091042    0.7229988 -4.27530783 1.908734e-05
IVq(26,28]  -2.397895    0.7385489 -3.24676555 1.167245e-03
IVq(28,42]  -1.856298    0.4808846 -3.86017349 1.133066e-04


> lapply( df[-1], function(x){ IVq <- cut(x, quantile(x), include = TRUE); table(IVq, df$dependent) })
$independent1
         
IVq        0  1
  [26,52] 38  1
  (52,60] 35  2
  (60,73] 37  2
  (73,91] 31  4

$independent2
         
IVq        0  1
  [15,23] 43  0
  (23,26] 44  2
  (26,28] 22  2
  (28,42] 32  5
```

At any rate I think I've demonstrated a more R-ish approach to calculating logits within quartiles. It also sets you up for a model comparison approach to examining departures from linearity as well as demonstrating possible pitfalls. If you had more events you might have considered looking at the change in deviance from the null model with the addition of a quartile factor on top of a simple linear model ... or even more powerfully using `poly` to create your comparison model.

In the past when working with datasets with adequate numbers of events I have chosen to split on the basis of quantiles calculated from an `event==1` subset rather than letting the splits be based on the whole dataset.